# create a drawable file

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [creating a drawable file to make a separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507659/creating-a-drawable-file-to-make-a-separator)

I am using the following code to create a divider between two fields:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

The code works perfectly but I want achieve something like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/divider" />
```

Doing so will help me combine 2 Views into one. However I don't know what code to write in the divider.xml file. I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
       <stroke android:color="#000000"/>
       <size android:width="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
       <stroke android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
       <size android:width="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2):

use `<layer-list> </layer-list>` instead of `<shape/>` to use more then one shape for drawable change your code as:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
       <stroke android:color="#000000"/>
       <size android:width="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
       <stroke android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
       <size android:width="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```