# creating a drawable file to make a separator

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to display a separator view in my activity:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/signoutbutton"
        android:background="@drawable/separator" />
```

My separator.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:height="54dp"
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:height="54dp"
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/blue" />

        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

however, I am achieving this   [image: separator]

The problem is that only the blue color is shown and not the white as I had stated in the drawable file. How can I correct this?

Comment: You may want to set the width of the white shape to 2dp. Right now the two shapes are perfectly one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try to use as below:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient 
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF" 
        android:startColor="@color/blue"
        android:angle="90" />                  
        </shape>
    </item>    
    </layer-list>
```

For more info here [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList)

Hope this help you

Comment: i set `android:left="1dp"` but i still got just one color

Comment: you should increase width of white rectangle to 2dp, and try again

Comment: setting width to 2 make the view invisible!!

Comment: i just edited my answer above, i change to use gradient, and now there is only one item tag. i have not tested it yet. Please try it,maybe it no need color of stroke

Comment: setting a gradient is fine but sets a gradual change in the colors. But i want two solid strokes